# Two digit numbers

Tags: visual-c++

I need a program that takes a two digit number such as "22" and returns "Twenty Two". I have the following started for the main method but have nothing for the string method

```
        static string TwoDigit(int n)
    {

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, TwoDigit(i));
        for (int i = 20; i <= 110; i += 7)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, TwoDigit(i));
    }
```

Comment: wow, i remember this algorithm in college day .. I created a lengthy code for it.. Then atlast.. i got a solution a next day...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an existing program but it would be easy to write the function.
I would convert the int to a string then do a switch statement on each character.
The first switch would handle the "Twenty", "Thirty", etc.
The second switch would handle one, two, three, etc.
You will need to have a special case for the teens that just spits out the word for each.

Answer (score 0):

Just take time in your reseach. If you don't know how to do it, I would advise to parse the int number by one number and then format the text via case.

```
switch (int)
case 1:
cout << "one";
switch (int)
case 2:
cout << "two";
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to just evaluate both digits separately and match them up to string values stored in two arrays.

So for example, you might have these two arrays...

```
tens[0] = ""
tens[1] = ""
tens[2] = "Twenty"
tens[3] = "Thirty"
tens[4] = "Forty"
tens[5] = "Fifty"
tens[6] = "Sixty"
```

etc...

```
ones[0] = ""
ones[1] = "One"
ones[2] = "Two"
ones[3] = "Three"
```

etc...

And then if the number is >= 20, you can simply take the first digit and use it as your index for the tens array, and your second digit and use it as your index for your ones array.  If the number is between 10 and 19, you'll need some special logic to handle it.

Comment: You need to create any array list for `teens`

Comment: Yeah, like I said, anything between 10 and 19 would need separate logic.  Either store those in a separate array, or just use a switch statement, whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize this function

   ```
   function Ones_String(number1) {

       if (number1 == 1) {
           string1 = "One";
       } elseif (number2 == 9) {
           string1 = "Nine";
       } elseif (number2 == 10) {
           string1 = "Ten";
       } elseif (number2 == 0)  {
           string1 = "Zero";
       } else {
           string1 = ""; // empty value
       }

       return string1;
   }


   function Tens_String(number2) {

       if (number2 == 2) {
           string2 = "Twenty";
       } elseif (number2 == 3) {
           string2 = "Thirty";
       } elseif (number2 == 9) {
           string2 = "Ninety";
       } else {
           string2 = ""; // emtpy value

       }
       return string2;
   }



   function teens_string(number3) {

       if (number3 == 11) {
           string3 = "Eleven";
       } elseif (number3 == 12) {
           string3 = "Tweleve";
       } else {
           string3 = "Nineteen";
       }

       return string3;
   }
   ```

If given number < 11 then call `Ones_string()`

If it is number >= 11 then do below logic

1. First : get the seconds digit value and call `Tens_String();`
2. Second : get the first digit vallue and call `Ones_string();`

And this algorithm applies till 99 .. Last used in 2006 at College on C++..

Whatever i mentioned is an algorithm / logic to detect.. not the perfect code