# Converting three digit numbers to text

Tags: c#

I am having some trouble doing this for the three digit. I can do it for the two digit numbers but when I add an if statement to the string TwoDigit it tells me unreachable code detected. This is what I have tried:-

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] digitWords =
        { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
            "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
            "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen",
            "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };

        static string[] tenWords =
        { "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty",
          "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

        static string[] hundredWords = { "One-hundred", "two-hundred",
          "three-hundred", "four-hundred", "five-hundred", "six-hundred",
          "seven-hundred", "eight-hundred", "nine-hundred"}

        static string TwoDigit(int num)
        {
            if (num < 0 || num > 99) return "";
            if (num < 20) return digitWords[num];
            if (num % 10 == 0)
                return tenWords[num / 10];
            else
                return tenWords[num / 10] + "-" + digitWords[num % 10];

            if (num % 100 == 0)
                return digitWords[num / 100] + "-" + hundredWords[num % 100];
            else
                return digitWords[num / 100] + "-" + hundredWords[num % 100] + "-" + digitWords[num % 100];
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, TwoDigit(i));
            for (int i = 20; i <= 99; i +=7)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, TwoDigit(i));
            for (int i = 100; i <= 1100; i += 7)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, TwoDigit(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't keep creating questions for the same problem: [First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352149/two-digit-numbers) [Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389624/numbers-2-to-words-two)

Answer (score 0):

You could be much more clear about where the error is occurring but I can see that the last half of `TwoDigit()` is unreachable. Since both cases of the `if` statement before it return, there's no way code below could be executed. The return statement exits the method and no further statements in the method are executed. That's why it's unreachable.

You can see how I did this in the code presented in my article [Converting Numbers to Words](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/converting-numbers-to-words).

Answer (score 0):

You have code with `return` in both branches - as result code after that `if` condition will never be executed:

```
   if (condition)
   {
      return 1;
   }
   else 
   { 
     return 2;
   }
   // never will reach here
   var i = 1; // unreachable code.
```

Answer (score 0):

For the particular problem of the error you're getting:

Your 3rd if statement will always return a value, therefore you'll never reach the 4th if statement. (Remember once you return you're done with that function, and the rest of the code wont be executed!)

Also, you may want to rethink your logic here, as entering any value > 99 will just return "" as the final answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could fix this by adding a string at the top of TwoDigit that concatenates different values onto it and then returns the newstring at the end:

```
static string TwoDigit(int num)
{
    string newstring = ""; 

    if (num < 0 || num > 99) return "";
    if (num < 20) return digitWords[num];
    if (num % 10 == 0)
        newstring += tenWords[num / 10];
    else
        newstring += tenWords[num / 10] + "-" + digitWords[num % 10];

    if (num % 100 == 0)
        newstring += digitWords[num / 100] + "-" + hundredWords[num % 100];
    else
        newstring += digitWords[num / 100] + "-" + hundredWords[num % 100] + "-" + 
              digitWords[num % 100];

   return newstring; 
}
```

Something like that should work if I'm understanding you correctly.

The reason this is happening (as mentioned by others) is that the first if/else block will always exit the function no matter what value is passed in. Your compiler is detecting this and throwing you an error because it has a feeling that you're doing something that you didn't intend to. (C# is strongly typed, the compiler doesn't allow a lot of things similar to this like a language like C or C++ would, C or C++ would allow this but you would get unintended results and logic errors)

EDIT: upon further reflection you would need to change the order that you concatenate the numbers (hundreds first, tens second, ones last) in order for it to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code on SO some time ago, and believe it to be an admirable bit of compact Linq to solve this problem. I cannot find the post now, so if someone recognized it, and can link to the original solution, that would be great. I am not the one to receive credit for this.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, long> numberTable =
    new Dictionary<string, long>
    {{"zero",0},{"one",1},{"two",2},{"three",3},{"four",4},
    {"five",5},{"six",6},{"seven",7},{"eight",8},{"nine",9},
    {"ten",10},{"eleven",11},{"twelve",12},{"thirteen",13},
    {"fourteen",14},{"fifteen",15},{"sixteen",16},
    {"seventeen",17},{"eighteen",18},{"nineteen",19},{"twenty",20},
    {"thirty",30},{"forty",40},{"fifty",50},{"sixty",60},
    {"seventy",70},{"eighty",80},{"ninety",90},{"hundred",100},
    {"thousand",1000},{"million",1000000},{"billion",1000000000},
    {"trillion",1000000000000},{"quadrillion",1000000000000000},
    {"quintillion",1000000000000000000}};

    public static long ToLong(string numberString)
    {
        var numbers = Regex.Matches(numberString, @"\w+").Cast<Match>()
             .Select(m => m.Value.ToLowerInvariant())
             .Where(v => numberTable.ContainsKey(v))
             .Select(v => numberTable[v]);
        long acc = 0, total = 0L;
        foreach (var n in numbers)
        {
            if (n >= 1000)
            {
                total += (acc * n);
                acc = 0;
            }
            else if (n >= 100)
            {
                acc *= n;
            }
            else acc += n;
        }
        return (total + acc) * (numberString.StartsWith("minus",
              StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? -1 : 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this intersting solution [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/converting-numbers-to-words):

```
namespace NumToText
{
    static class NumberToText
    {
        private static string[] _ones =
        {
            "zero",
            "one",
            "two",
            "three",
            "four",
            "five",
            "six",
            "seven",
            "eight",
            "nine"
        };

        private static string[] _teens =
        {
            "ten",
            "eleven",
            "twelve",
            "thirteen",
            "fourteen",
            "fifteen",
            "sixteen",
            "seventeen",
            "eighteen",
            "nineteen"
        };

        private static string[] _tens =
        {
            "",
            "ten",
            "twenty",
            "thirty",
            "forty",
            "fifty",
            "sixty",
            "seventy",
            "eighty",
            "ninety"
        };

        // US Nnumbering:
        private static string[] _thousands =
        {
            "",
            "thousand",
            "million",
            "billion",
            "trillion",
            "quadrillion"
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a numeric value to words suitable for the portion of
        /// a check that writes out the amount.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Value to be converted</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Convert(decimal value)
        {
            string digits, temp;
            bool showThousands = false;
            bool allZeros = true;

            // Use StringBuilder to build result
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            // Convert integer portion of value to string
            digits = ((long)value).ToString();
            // Traverse characters in reverse order
            for (int i = digits.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int ndigit = (int)(digits[i] - '0');
                int column = (digits.Length - (i + 1));

                // Determine if ones, tens, or hundreds column
                switch (column % 3)
                {
                    case 0:        // Ones position
                        showThousands = true;
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            // First digit in number (last in loop)
                            temp = String.Format("{0} ", _ones[ndigit]);
                        }
                        else if (digits[i - 1] == '1')
                        {
                            // This digit is part of "teen" value
                            temp = String.Format("{0} ", _teens[ndigit]);
                            // Skip tens position
                            i--;
                        }
                        else if (ndigit != 0)
                        {
                            // Any non-zero digit
                            temp = String.Format("{0} ", _ones[ndigit]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // This digit is zero. If digit in tens and hundreds
                            // column are also zero, don't show "thousands"
                            temp = String.Empty;
                            // Test for non-zero digit in this grouping
                            if (digits[i - 1] != '0' || (i > 1 && digits[i - 2] != '0'))
                                showThousands = true;
                            else
                                showThousands = false;
                        }

                        // Show "thousands" if non-zero in grouping
                        if (showThousands)
                        {
                            if (column > 0)
                            {
                                temp = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                                    temp,
                                    _thousands[column / 3],
                                    allZeros ? " " : ", ");
                            }
                            // Indicate non-zero digit encountered
                            allZeros = false;
                        }
                        builder.Insert(0, temp);
                        break;

                    case 1:        // Tens column
                        if (ndigit > 0)
                        {
                            temp = String.Format("{0}{1}",
                                _tens[ndigit],
                                (digits[i + 1] != '0') ? "-" : " ");
                            builder.Insert(0, temp);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:        // Hundreds column
                        if (ndigit > 0)
                        {
                            temp = String.Format("{0} hundred ", _ones[ndigit]);
                            builder.Insert(0, temp);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Append fractional portion/cents
            builder.AppendFormat("and {0:00}/100", (value - (long)value) * 100);

            // Capitalize first letter
            return String.Format("{0}{1}",
                Char.ToUpper(builder[0]),
                builder.ToString(1, builder.Length - 1));
        }
    }
}
```